# Ошибка Fatal error: Cannot redeclare

Tags: php

выходит такая ошибка:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getUserInfo() (previously declared in C:\Users\i654\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\local.cup.io\lib\user.php:2) in C:\Users\i654\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\local.cup.io\lib\user.php on line 7

```
 <?php
    function getUserInfo($user_id, $fields='`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`') {  
        $link = connectDatabase();
        $is_email_exist = $link->prepare("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `id` = :user_id");
        $is_email_exist->execute(array(':user_id' => $user_id));
        return $is_email_exist->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    function isUserAuth() {
        return !empty($_SESSION['user_id']);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что файл с функцией подключается в разных местах через `include` или `require`. Поэтому получается, что в файл вставляется кусок кода с одними и теми же функциями.

Решение: надо подключить файл с функциями единожды в файле в одном месте

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!